# How do you assign an IBOutlet programmatically using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I added a bar button item programmatically to a view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

Now I want to assign that bar button item to an `IBOutlet` programmatically. How would I do that using Swift?

Comment: The `IB` of `IBOutlet` stands for **I**nterface **B**uilder and it represents a connection from the interface builder to the source code.  Assigning an `IBOutlet` programmatically couldn't make less sense.  What are you *actually* trying to do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `IB` of `IBOutlet` stands for **I**nterface **B**uilder and it represents a connection from the interface builder to the source code. Assigning an `IBOutlet` programmatically couldn't make less sense.

An `IBOutlet` is simply an instance variable of a class which is tied to part of the interface or can be set via the interface builder.  If we want a reference to our button (in the same way we'd have a reference to it if we made it in the interface builder), we simply add a property to our class, and then assign our newly created button to that:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var someBarButton: UIBarButtonItem?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.someBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.someBarButton
    }
}
```

And now, `someBarButton` is our "IBOutlet".

---

**Some notes...**

There's a pretty decent chance we might not actually want to do things this way.

This creates an extra strong reference to the button (`self.navigationItem` already holds a strong reference to its `leftBarButtonItem`).

You'll notice, if you make an `IBOutlet` from interface builder, it is set up as a `weak` property.  So perhaps we want a weak property?

But we can actually do ourselves one better.  Try this on for size:

```
var leftNavBarButton: UIBarButtonItem? {
    get {
        return self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
    }
    set (newValue) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newValue
    }
}
```

Now, `self.leftNavBarButton` is essentially just a convenient way of accessing `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 1):

You mean to assign an action to the button in code instead of in IB. Your question is worded in a somewhat confusing way, but never mind.

You use the `target` and `action` arguments of the `UIBarButtonItem` constructor. `target` is your controller, typically `self`; `action` is a string that is a selector signature of your button handler contained by that controller.

```
    self.someBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .Plain, 
        target: self, action: "buttonHandler:")
```